# How to create a web page which seamlessly hosts a script on another webserver?

Tags: php, iframe

I have written a DNS security testing tool in PHP which relies on the webserver having BIND installed locally. I need to add this tool to our existing website however it's against policy to have BIND on the main web server. I have been allocated a new server if I need it and I'm trying to find the best solution to make this tool appear to be part of the main website (i.e. under the same domain e.g. domain.com/tool)

My first thought was to make a page on the main web server and host the tool within an iframe. This way, the tool can fit seamlessly into the existing site without having to recreate and maintain the sites themes and templates on the second server (header, footer etc). However, the script relies on being able to do a meta refresh redirect to a 2nd script which displays the results (the redirect is required to give time for the security tool to run). Im not sure if this can be done all within an iFrame. Any suggestions or methods that might be better than using an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just as an idea:** Your tool could generate a JSON response, and then you could use padded JSON to get it. With a little bit of work, you could do all the things you want using XMLHTTPRequests.